# Ways to display large amount of data from CSV files in HTML pages?

Tags: java, javascript, csv, plot, bigdata

guys.
I need to develop something to use at work, but I'm with some doubts, so I hope there's someone who can help me :)

**The situation:**
I work in the Information Security area of a company. We use the QualysGuard tool to search for vulnerabilities in our customers' servers. One of my functions is  managing the Key Performance Indicators (KPI's), to keep track of how many patches we have applied along the weeks. I download the data in CSV format and then I make A LOT of stuff in Excel to organize everything, sorted by Customers names, Operating Systems and Severity of the vulnerabilities.

**The Problem:**
There's a HUGE amount of data in the downloaded CSV files (Each file has like 35MB, and 80000+ rows) and I have to do a lot of repetitive work to finally make these files look good fine (create pivot tables, sort by assets, OS and severity, separate groups of different amounts of data (e.g. some customers have 100+ servers, which means there are way more vulnerabilities in their servers than in customers with, let's say, only 2 servers. And I have to do this every week. At the end of the month, I have to list the top-10 most vulnerable servers for each customer and for each OS. And also plot these data in graps.

**What I need:**
My boss asked me if I could create a system (preferably web-based) that can read these CSV files and display their data, and maybe plot some graphs with them.

**The question:**
What's the best way to do that? I thought of using PHP, I've got some experience with parsing CSV files data and working with them, but, since PHP is a server-side language, I think I won't be able to display the data dynamically. 
So I'd like to know what programming language would be the best one in this case? Would Javascript handle it? Or something with python or ruby? Or maybe some web-application with Java? Or even PHP, if combined with MySQL queries? (I'm not sure if I'll be able to use the company's databases for it, so, MySQL solutions aren't my first choices XD ) 
Has anybody ever had some troubles with something like this?
I'm not asking anyone to write programs to me, I just need some tips. 
Thanks to everyone who answers something :)
If there's no answer, thanks for at least reading :)

Comment: bad idea. don't deal with the csv files, at least not repetitively. load them into a DB and work from that. that way you parse them ONCE, and then can slice/dice the data as much you want in the db. leaving them in csv format would be hugely inefficient and wasteful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it doesn't matter the language. You'll have to load that to server for processing, as from JavaScript you have no access to local files.

My recommendation would be (if you really need to handle CSV files) is to load the files, generate a JSON object from the data and use the JSON object from the client side, using JavaScript.

Depending on the size of the file, you may want to page the data so you don't need to download the entire data. But it would be better to load it on DB, and then load data as needed using AJAX, and even plot it using some client-side component.

Comment: Thanks! My boss alowed me to use a mysql database, I got all data in it and everything going well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the dynamic thing than you can use php with ajax.
convert CSV to json/XML and parse to get your stuff, or you can use fgetcsv() function which gets line from file pointer and parse for CSV field. fgetcsv() function returns an array containing the field read.